# How to remove "the activating a license results with one Component popup" on application start(Just for others but works fine for me)?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, components, uicontrol, licenses.licx, grapecity

I have activated the one component license and used it in one of the application and created a .exe for that application. It's not popping up for me but when any third user is installing that .exe and open that app then it's popping up with the below trial version popup. There is no licenses.licx in my projects/solution. I have added the licx file(just found some keys on grapcity site) through Nuget package but they are empty. Below is the popup comes for third users:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are a licensed customer of GrapeCity/ComponentOne, so you should contact their support team directly... Submit a ticket via https://www.grapecity.com/support/contact and/or get in touch with them in other ways:

[image: grapecity]

Comment: I am using the license key provided by my Client so not logged in with my email id on grapcity. There is a way in which I can bind the license in exe though VS that's what i want.